# JavaScript removeNode() is not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom

I need to remove a node from a page, and for that I am using the below mentioned function

`document.getElementById(id).removeNode(true);`

This function works fine in IE but not in Chrome.
Could anyone tell me how should I do it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `removeChild`, it works in [most browsers](http://code.google.com/p/doctype/wiki/DocumentRemoveChildMethod).

Answer (score 1):

The function `removeNode()` seems to be [a Microsoft proprietary function](https://coderanch.com/t/668885/languages/removeNode-true-working#3123156), so probably only supported in Internet Explorer (IE).

Since the latest browsers are typically chromium-based (such as Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge "Wave" v79+) I replaced it with `remove()` and it seemed to fix the issue:

```
document.getElementById(id).remove();
```